# Linking two input fields in React

Tags: coffeescript, reactjs

I have a form with two inputs, which acts as a calculator of sorts. Think of something like a mortgage calculator.  A user needs to be able to input a value into input a (int or decimal), and have it calculate some value for input b.  Likewise, a user must be able to input a value into input b (int), and have it calculate a value for input a. The values should calculate as the user types.

I have the calculation working, but I'm running into problems when I try to either a: empty the field to start over; or b: attempt to input a decimal into input a.

In the first case, neither input will let me remove the final character. Even if I highlight the entire value and hit *backspace*, the input stays at whatever value was there.

In the second case, the decimal never takes.  If I try to type in `2.2`, I get `22` instead.

Per the React documentation, I'm using an `onChange` event handler, which sets the state of my component, and then the inputs display that state.

Code example is here:

```
  handleIntervalChange: ->
    iVal = parseFloat @refs.confidenceInterval.getDOMNode().value
    iVal = iVal/100
    lVal = parseFloat @refs.confidenceLevel.getDOMNode().value
    return false if _.isNaN ival
    docCount = @calcDocsByCLevel lVal, iVal
    docCount = null if _.isNaN(docCount) or docCount is Infinity
    @setState
      targetCLevel: lVal
      targetCInterval: iVal
      docCount: docCount

  handleDocChange: ->
    docCount = parseInt @refs.docCount.getDOMNode().value
    return false if _.isNaN docCount
    lVal = parseFloat @refs.confidenceLevel.getDOMNode().value
    @setState
      targetCLevel: lVal
      targetCInterval: @calcIntervalByDocCount lVal, docCount
      docCount: docCount

  render: ->
    <fieldset>
      <div className='controls'>
        <label htmlFor='confidence-interval'>
          Confidence interval (%)
        </label>
        {<ValidatorTooltip errors={@state.errors['confidence-interval']}/> if @state.errors}
        <input type='text' id='confidence-interval'
        className={cIntervalClasses} ref='confidenceInterval'
        value={@state.targetCInterval * 100}
        onKeyUp={@handleKeyUp} onChange={@handleIntervalChange} />
      </div>
      <div className='controls'>
        <label htmlFor='doc-count'>Number of documents</label>
        {<ValidatorTooltip errors={@state.errors['doc-count']}/> if @state.errors}
        <input type='text' id='doc-count' className={docClasses}
        ref='docCount' onChange={@handleDocChange} onKeyUp={@handleKeyUp}
        value={@state.docCount} />
      </div>
    </fieldset>
```

Comment: [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27613490/1074592)

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) reproducing the problem?

Comment: Trying to, but I can't get the component to render. http://jsfiddle.net/uLpxfkxn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. The problem was in my calculation methods - I needed some logic to catch if the document or interval fields were blank (and would then render the other fields blank).